# Is object[0] sort of a default key for an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here's a small JavaScript snippet:

```
  var re_words = /\w+/g;

  var words;
  while (words = re_words.exec(' here are a few (sic!) words ')) {
     alert(words);
  }
```

The loop alerts the words found in the input string, which is what I expected, because all the JavaScript tutorials tell me so.

Now, **typeof(words)** results in **object**.

Therefore, I would have expected **alert(words)** to give me **object**.

If I inspect the elements in words, I found them to be 0, "index" and "input". The element words[0] is the same as what is alerted with words.

So, the question is: is the element 0 sort of a default index for an Object in JavaScript which is returned if it is defined.

Or asked differently: why does **alert(words)** give the same effect as **alert(words[0])**? I would have expected alert(words) to give a "Object".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [result of executing a regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is an Array, which is a special kind of Object. The array also has two properties, index and input. words[0] contains the matched characters. Calling `.toString()` on an array (as is implicitly done by `alert()`) joins the elements of the array with a comma (after calling `.toString()` on each of those). In this case, since there was only one element, the comma was superfluous, so the result of calling `.toString()` on the array is the same as the first element in the array.

(Not sure what browser you're using; in Firefox, `alert(words)` gives `'here'`, then `'are'`, and so on until finally it gives the string `'words'`.)

Comment: +1. `words!==words[0]` and `['a']!=='a'`, only their string representations are the same.